# Resolve relative relocations in partial link

Tags: linux, ld, relocation

I've noticed that using `-r` to do a partial link doesn't actually resolve any relocations, it seems, even if they could be resolved via relative addressing. For example, consider `f.o` and `g.o`, with `f.o` containing `f()` which calls `g()` within `g.o`. Before linking, the disassembly and relocations are as expected. After partial linking to a new file `h.o` (via `ld -r -o h.o f.o g.o`), however, there is still a relocation for the call to `g()`, even though in theory it could have been resolved with a relative address.

Here is the disassembly of `h.o` (`objdump -d h.o`), containing `f()` and `g()`. You can see that the call to `g()` is still unresolved:

```
h.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <f>:
   0:       55                      push   %rbp
   1:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  9 <f+0x9>
   9:       90                      nop
   a:       5d                      pop    %rbp
   b:       c3                      retq

000000000000000c <g>:
   c:       55                      push   %rbp
   d:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  10:       90                      nop
  11:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  12:       c3                      retq
```

Here is the relocation table of `h.o` (`objdump -r h.o`):

```
h.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE
0000000000000005 R_X86_64_PC32     g-0x0000000000000004


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.eh_frame]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE
0000000000000020 R_X86_64_PC32     .text
0000000000000058 R_X86_64_PC32     .text+0x000000000000000c
```

So, just wondering whether or not there was any way to force the relocation to be performed via a relative address during a partial link. I tried compiling the code with `-fpic`, but that still did not cause the relocation to be performed during the partial link.

Note that I have no goal, application, or reason for this. Just exploring the functionality and capabilities of `ld`.

Comment: I also learnt that `gcc` does not resolve single-file function call relocations by default either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391965/what-is-partial-linking-in-gnu-linker/53959624#53959624

Answer (score 2):

Per [this reference](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries/) it looks like the reason that the relative symbols are not resolved is to give the linked more flexibility. If we wanted to instead resolve the symbol `g` to a different address, we would need to change those jumps in the code.

However, if you change your symbol `g` to be static, then the linker will resolve the jumps. In that case, the symbol is no longer exported and thus not manipulable by future linker calls.