# Does the --force-lto gem5 scons build option speed up simulation significantly and how does it compare to a gem5.fast build?

Tags: gem5

While looking for ways to speed up my simulation, I came across the `--force-lto` option.

I've heard about LTO (Link Time Optimization) before, so that made me wonder why isn't `--force-lto` the default while building gem5?

Would that make a simulation go much faster than a gem5.fast build compared to a gem5.opt build?

Answer (score 1):

In gem5 fe15312aae8007967812350f8cdac9ad766dcff7 (2019), the gem5.fast build already enables LTO by default, so you generally never want to use that option explicitly, but rather want just `gem5.opt`.

Other things to also keep in about `.fast`:

- it [also removes `-g` and so you get no debug symbols](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/05c4c2b566ce351ab217b2bd7035562aa7a76570/src/SConscript#L1138). I wonder why, since that does not make runs any faster.
- it also turns on `NDEBUG`, which has the standard library effect of [disabling `assert`s entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290509/debug-vs-ndebug), but plus some gem5 specific effects spread throughout the code with `#ifndef NDEBUG` checks
- it disables `TRACING_ON`, which makes DPRINTF and family become empty statements as seen at: src/base/trace.hh

Those effects can be seen easily [at `src/SConstruct`](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/05c4c2b566ce351ab217b2bd7035562aa7a76570/src/SConscript#L1138).

That option exists because the more common `gem5.opt` build also uses [partial linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391965/what-is-partial-linking-in-gnu-linker/53959624#53959624), which in some versions of GCC was incompatible with LTO.

Therefore, as its the name suggests, `--force-lto` forces the use of LTO together with partial linking, which might not be stable. That's why I recommend that you use `gem5.fast` rather than touching `--force-lto`.

The goal of partial linking is presumably to speed up the link step, which can easily be the bottleneck in a "change on file, rebuild, relink, test" loop, although in my experiments it is not clear that it is efficient at doing that. Today it might just be a relic from the past.

To try to speed up linking, I recommend that you try `scons --gold-linker` instead, which [uses the GOLD linker instead of ld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476093/replacing-ld-with-gold-any-experience/53921263#53921263). Note that this option was more noticeably effective for gem5.debug however.

I have found that `gem5.fast` is generally 20% faster than `gem5.opt` for Atomic CPUs.