# How can I automatically link in the dependency of a dependency in VS 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, project-reference

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, with a lot of project and solution files.  But now I find myself in a bit of dependency hell with ProjectReferences:

- Project `Simple` produces a static lib.
- Projects `Foo` and `Bar` depend on `Simple`, and also produce static libs.
- Project `Module` depends on `Foo` and produces a DLL.
- Project `Module2` depends on `Bar` and produces a DLL.

So the dependency tree looks like this:

```
                Simple
                  |
     ____________/ \__________
     |                        |
    Foo                      Bar
     |                        |
   Module                   Module2
```

With `ProjectReferences`, I can make `Module` depend on `Foo` and automatically link `Foo.lib`.  This works fine.

**But**, is there a way for `Module` to automatically link in `Simple.lib`?

It seems like that should be possible.  `Module` depends on `Foo`, which depends on `Simple`, so it seems like it should be able to have an option for "link in the output of my references and my references' references".  But I can't find anything that lets me do that.

The "Link Library Dependencies" option doesn't do it.  It only links in Foo.lib, and then I get a linking error about unresolved external symbols (symbols which are defined in Simple.lib).

Setting "Link Library Dependencies" to `true` for the `Foo`->`Simple` and `Bar`->`Simple` references seems to work at first, until you have a project that uses both `Foo` and `Bar`.  That setting actually embeds `Simple.lib` inside of `Foo.lib` and `Bar.lib`, and then you get "symbol is already defined" errors if you try to use both `Foo.lib` and `Bar.lib`.  And that's the correct error - I don't actually want to put `Simple.lib` inside of any other lib.

I can add a `ProjectReferece` from `Module` to `Simple`, but that's tedious to set in every project that uses `Foo`, and it's violating the encapsulation of `Foo`.  `Module` should not need to know about `Simple`.  Obviously the linker needs to know about `Simple`, but it should be able to figure that out by following ProjectReferences.

Here's why this matters:  Suppose, during maintenance, a new project is created:  `Basic`, which creates a static lib, and `Simple` depends on `Basic`.  Now we have to update every single project that has a `ProjectReference` to `Simple` directly or through another ProjectReference (in this example it's only two projects, `Module` and `Module2`, but in reality it's dozens).  That's tedious.

**tl;dr** Is there a way to automatically link in the static libs of my dependencies?

Comment: This is a little different from what you are asking, but what I usually do is add a pragma linker comment in a header file to automatically include the lib files needed.

`#pragma comment(lib,"simple.lib")`

Comment: @TheSteve, I've done that too, but that can cause problems with link order dependency.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445023/c-can-you-build-one-static-library-into-another]

Comment: @PermanentGuest, he was trying to embed one lib in another.  I don't want to do that.  I'm looking for a solution that makes use of the ProjectReferences.

Comment: actually, it may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437538/vs2010-static-linking-issue . It's a VS bug, that's "Fixed".  I'll install SP1 and see if that actually fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in Visual Studio 2010:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/638534/unresolved-externals-when-build-a-vc-project-with-chained-static-lib-dependencies#details

Unfortunately, Microsoft closed the bug as "fixed" -- which isn't quite true.  It's more of a workaround, but it's not what I would consider a real fix.  (A real fix would be a patch or a service pack, not something that needs to be manually tweaked on every machine).

The "fix" is to do the following:

Modify `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\Microsoft.cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CPPBuild.Targets`
And change the line:

```
<Target Name="GetResolvedLinkLibs" Returns="@(LibFullPath)"
 DependsOnTargets="$(CommonBuildOnlyTargets)">
```

To

```
<Target Name="GetResolvedLinkLibs" Returns="@(LibFullPath)"
 DependsOnTargets="$(CommonBuildOnlyTargets);ResolvedLinkLib">
```

So, just add the **;ResolvedLinkLib** part to that file.  Then VS will link in dependencies of dependencies.