# library using winsocks: unresolved external symbol

Tags: visual-c++, static-libraries, winsock

I created a library which makes use of winsocks, I compile it with following commands:

```
cl /c myLib.c /link ws2_32.lib
lib myLib.obj
```

thus obtaining myLib.lib, everything's ok.

Now, I wrote a test program, test.c in which I do:

```
#include "myLib.h"

//... i use some functions //
```

I compile it with

```
cl test.c /link myLib.lib
```

but I get:

> myLib.lib(myLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_connec
>   t@12
>   myLib.lib(myLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_htons@
>   4
>   myLib.lib(myLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_inet_a
>   ddr@4
>   myLib.lib(myLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_socket
>   @12
>   myLib.lib(myLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_WSASta
>   rtup@8
>   myLib.lib(myLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_WSACle
>   anup@0
>   logbus.lib(logbus.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_closes
>   ocket@4
>   test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals

**edit:
Ok, if I compile adding a link to ws2_32.lib too it works. 
Anyway I don't like it: I already linked this library when I created mine, so I just want to link to myLib.lib...is it possibile?**

Answer (score 1):

You could try the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157735/218597), which is basically to include `ws2_32.lib` in your own library:

```
cl /c myLib.c /link ws2_32.lib
lib /out:myLib.lib myLib.obj ws2_32.lib
```

*In theory* this would make a composite library.  The issue, however, is if you distribute `myLib.lib` - I'm not sure how legal it would be, as you would be including copyrighted code.

As an aside, but I include it as it's quite interesting and a slightly relevant, Raymond Chen recently wrote a series of articles on the [Classical Linker Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/tags/linker/).

Answer (score 1):

I solved using the #pragma directive to include the win2_32 into myLib.lib.