# Remove boost dependency when linking to a library that uses boost with cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, static-libraries

I am trying to create a library which uses boost filesystem within but I don't want to have to add that dependency to the executable that uses that library. I am using CMAKE as it has to be cross platform.

In the cmake file I have added a preprocessor definition 'BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB' to not auto link and set cmake to use static libraries. This all compiles and creates the library. The cmake code is shown below.

```
 set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
 add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
 find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)
 include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

target_link_libraries(Utility
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

But when I link in the library I get errors like the one below.

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" ...
```

If I add the boost filesystem and boost system libraries to the the additional dependencies in the Librarian for my Library, the errors in the executable go away. Is there a way I can do this with CMAKE?

Comment: so the question is very misleading? You don't want to stop autolinking (because already do that!) but instead want to manually add import libraries using CMake? Please clarify

Comment: Does CMake say that the libraries are found when you run configure? Maybe you compiled them for a different version of MSVC?

Comment: Cmake finds the right version, I made sure I cleaned out the stage folder built using the right compiler and using link=static. Checked cmake picked up the right folder. I have also tried using the runtime-link=static version of the boost libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is possible with visual studio but not generally:

[Linking static libraries to other static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the Boost find module called `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`. Set it to "ON". My canned Boost CMake looks like:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost ...)
```