# Problems compiling to a static library with CMake

Tags: c, linker, cmake, static-linking

I'm trying to compile a project into a statically linked library with CMake. Here I'm checking if `BFD` and `Iberty` are availabe, and if they are I compile a modified `backtrace-symbols.c` into an `OBJECT` Library, and statically link that object into the project along with the `BFD`, `Iberty`, and `DL` libraries it depends on.  When I try to use the resultant static library in a project, I get errors on `BFD` functions that are used in `backtrace-symbols.c` saying they are undefined.

How can I ensure that `BFD`, `Iberty`, and `DL` are also statically linked into this library so that the user won't have to worry about linking against them in their project?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(simplog)

configure_file (
    "SimpLogConfig.h.in"
    "SimpLogConfig.h"
    @ONLY
)

set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang" )

find_library( BFD_LIBRARY bfd )
find_library( IBERTY_LIBRARY iberty )

find_path(
    IBERTY_HEADER_PATH libiberty.h
    PATHS
        /usr/include/libiberty
        /usr/local/include/libiberty.h
)

include_directories(
    ${IBERTY_HEADER_PATH}
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
)

set( PACKAGE "SimpLog" )
set( PACKAGE_VERSION "0.0.1" )
if( BFD_LIBRARY AND IBERTY_LIBRARY )
    option( BETTER_BACKTRACE "" ON )
    add_library( backtrace-symbols OBJECT backtrace-symbols.c )
    add_library( simplog STATIC simplog.c $<TARGET_OBJECTS:backtrace-symbols> )
    target_link_libraries( simplog ${BFD_LIBRARY} ${IBERTY_LIBRARY} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} )
else()
    option( BETTER_BACKTRACE "" OFF )
    add_library( simplog STATIC simplog.c )
endif()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you cannot merge multiple static libraries into one. This is because most C++ compilers do not support this feature, so CMake also cannot support it without breaking half of its generators.

The way you solve this instead is by building dependency hierarchies using `target_link_libraries`. In your case, it looks like `backtrace_symbols` depends on `iberty` and `bfd`, while `simplog` in turn depends on `backtrace-symbols`. You can model those dependencies like this:

```
add_library( backtrace-symbols backtrace-symbols.c )
target_link_libraries( backtracesymbols ${IBERTY_LIBRARY} ${BFD_LIBRARY} )
add_library( simplog STATIC simplog.c )
target_link_libraries( simplog backtracesymbols )
```

Now any executable that links to `simplog` will automatically pull in all dependencies in the correct order, including transitive ones. On the other hand, if you want to ship binaries of your library to other developers, you need to include not only the `.a` file for `simplog`, but also the ones for `backtracesymbols`, `iberty` and `bfd`. If you want to ship only a single file, you have to make `simplog` a dynamic library instead.

Ensure that you always specify library dependencies at the level in the hierarchy where they are first used! Even though the linker will only actually need them when linking the final executable, specifying them in this way ensures that the linker pulls them in in the right order.
Failing to do so can lead to undefined symbol errors like those you experienced.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I was attempting the impossible. Also, thanks for the CMake/linking tips!