# Link static library with static library

Tags: c, linker, autotools, automake

I have a `Makefile.am` with two `noinst_LIBRARIES`, and one of them needs to link with the other.

Adding it to the `CFLAGS` throws a compiler warning, but as far as I know, automake likes to freak out about using `LDADD` with libraries, since they are not complete programs.

How can I do this, assuming `libb.a` needs to pull in `liba.a`?

Comment: You don't link static libraries, they are added to your binary.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're trying to do, but note that you cannot link one static library to another. They're just a collection of object files, and there is no mechanism in static libraries to indicate that they depend on another library.

Comment: @nos true, however if there is dependency, i.e. if `liba.a` uses symbols from `libb.a` then when including the libraries in your binary you must be careful about the order in which you pass them. Which means that circular dependencies are **not allowed**.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries)

Comment: Copy past the compiler warning.

Comment: @iharob Circular dependencies can be handled,  but you must mention the libraries several times when linking the program that uses them, e.g. pass the flags `-lA -lB -lA`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two "ar" static libraries into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one)

Comment: This does make sense in the context of `libtool` libraries, where you can create convenience libraries with `noinst_LTLIBRARIES`, and use: `libb_la_LIBADD = ./liba.la` to let `libtool` take care of resolving static library dependencies. But as others have pointed out, these are just archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. Actually, what you are trying to do doesn't really make sense. Static libraries are just archives containing object files and a table of contents. Put simply, you can think of a static library as a `.zip` containing `.o` files.

The linking phase only takes place when compiling a shared object or executable. When your program is linked against `liba.a`, you also need to specify `-static -lb` or similar and that's it.

Comment: I suppose I was considering "linking" the static libraries to be "include the object files from the other one in the final one".

Comment: That's very far from linking :) if you meant merging two archives into another, there is no universal way of doing so (because static libraries are not meant to be handled like that), but you might find platform-specific ways. For instance, GCC/Clang static libraries are `ar` archives that you could extract, merge and repack. Instead, MSVC has a tool for that. Be careful with conflicting names or symbols though.