# Merged Library with LIB.EXE throws LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'PocoFoundationmt.lib'

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, cmake, static-libraries

So, I'm building a static C++11 Windows Library A.lib which uses 'PocoFoundationmt.lib' and a few other third party libraries and I don't want to have the Test application (Z.exe) which uses A.lib to have a long list of all libraries in the linker command. So, I want to merge all the third party libraries into a composite.lib

The project for A.lib is generated by cmake and the CMakeLists.txt file has the following lines:

```
add_library(A STATIC ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE PocoFoundationmt.lib OtherStaticLibs.lib)
```

Now, after I build A.lib, I execute LIB.EXE to combine libraries as suggested in a lot of threads:

eg. [Linking static libraries to other static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
LIB.EXE /OUT:composite.lib A.lib PocoFoundationmt.lib OtherStaticLibs.lib
```

However, when I link the composite.lib to my Test application, it always throws this error :

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'PocoFoundationmt.lib'
```

A lot of threads suggested to combine libraries this way. Is this the correct approach or do I have to mention all libraries in the linker input parameter of my Test app (Z.exe) ?

Comment: You should pass absolute paths to `target_link_libraries()`.

Comment: @drescherjm I am combining the libraries using /MACHINE:x86 option. All my static libraries are also 32-bit. Also, PocoFoundationmt.lib works fine when I link it with my Test project so I know that is not a corrupt file. It's just that if I combine PocoFoundationmt.lib and other 3rd party libraries in one library that I see this issue.

Comment: @arrowd I am passing the absolute paths. I wrote this just as an example. Sorry for that.

Comment: I see the problem is `PocoFoundationmt.lib` is still in linker libraries for Test. You need to get it out of the list if you want to use the combined library. Is it listed in Linker/ Input / Additional Dependencies for Test? If it is not perhaps there is a `#pragma comment (lib, PocoFoundationmt.lib)` in one of your headers.

Comment: @drescherjm No, PocoFoundationmt.lib is not listed anywhere, neither in Additional Dependencies nor there is a pragma comment anywhere.

Comment: The libraries that you are combining are all static libraries (not import libraries / no dlls involved)?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes. All Poco libraries are created with POCO_STATIC enabled and other libraries are also static. And I was just able to successfully build the Test project by including the directory where PocoFoundationmt.lib is present in the Linker / General / Additional Library Directories. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: ***I'm not sure why this is happening.*** Me either.