# Combine static C++ libraries

Tags: c++, build, compilation

Is there a way (preferably in Visual Studio) to "pack" all used libraries of a library into that library? For example, using boost in your library and building the library with boost included automatically, so when you link it in visual studio, you only have to link your library, not boost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking static libraries to other static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e17b885t.aspx use this command to extract all the object files from all libraries and then use it again to combine them all into a new library.