# Linking a static library to a shared library in MSVC causes unresolved symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, dynamic-linking

I'm building a **dynamic** library `c` which is linked to a static library `b`.

The static library `b` is statically linked to the static library `a`.

The cmake for `c`, roughly looks like this (the cmakes for `a` and `b` are quite similar):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(c)

include_directories(../b/src)
link_directories(../b/Debug)

add_library(c SHARED src/c.cpp)
target_link_libraries(c PRIVATE b)
```

The issue I'm facing is related to the fact that `c` can't see references to functions defined in `a`:

```
b.lib(b.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl a(void)" (?a@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl b(void)" (?b@@YAHXZ) [C:\Users\user\Workspace\garbage\c\c.vcxproj]
C:\Users\user\Workspace\garbage\c\Debug\c.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\Users\user\Workspace\garbage\c\c.vcxproj]
```

Is there any way for `c` to properly link?

Related questions:

[Linking static libraries to other static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries)

Comment: static libraries are not linked ,they are merely a collection of object-files put together. Executables (exe's & dll's) are linked ,so to make an executable you need to supply all static libraries that are needed.

Comment: @engf-010 ??? [Static linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)#Static_linking)

Comment: @J. Doe: Yes ,that's exactly what I said in my comment.

Comment: @engf-010 Thats still called linking.

Comment: @J. Doe: Yes ,in the process of making an executable. That is either an exe or a dll.

Comment: @engf-010 so in this case the solution would be to provide both `a` and `b` when I want to produce a `c` executable? Reason being, statically linking `a` to `b` won't bundle the contents of `a` into `b`, it actually won't do anything at all

Comment: Precisely ,I couldn't have worded it better.

Comment: The process of making a library is often called archiving. Hence the .a extension of libraries on unix-like systems.

Answer (score -1):

Something tells me that your linker output is not quite right. It looks like perhaps `a` and `b` are trying to be exported classes.

That aside, this line tells us that `b` cannot actually see some symbol (perhaps the class default constructor) for library (class) `a`:

`b.lib(b.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl a(void)" (?a@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl b(void)" (?b@@YAHXZ)`

In fact, your CMake example never links `a` to `b` and, your original questions says that `b` is linked into `a`. If you mean what you said in your question, you linker shows the logic error.

Comment: The CMakes for `a` and `b` are not shown for brevity, as they are quite similar (`b` links `a` in an identical way, while `a` links nothing).

In this case, `int a() {return 42;}` and `int b() {return a();}` and `int c(){return b()}` are all functions