# Boost libraries static linking

Tags: c++, boost, static-libraries

I've made a static library project which is using some boost libraries in its work. I've hidden all signs of boost from my static library header files as well.

Now I'm trying to create test console app with my library. I've set up include and lib paths to my library directories and got an "fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib'".

If I include path to .lib files of boost it works, but I wish not to do that in order to not have any dependencies for my library using. Can I achieve that?

Also I've tried to create composite lib file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries) with command "lib /out:composite.lib Client.lib libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76.lib" and rename composite.lib as Client.lib. I've got bunch of warnings LNK4006 (already defined in Client.lib ... second definition ignored). Result has appropriate size as sum of initial libraries sizes, but still doesn't work.