# Is ar rcs in GCC a valid translation of link /lib in CL?

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, build, cl

I have this command on Windows:
**A.obj
link /lib /out:B.lib A.obj**

I want to do exactly the same but with GCC 4.8.5 in Linux

I tried with
**A.o
ar rcs B.a A.o**
and it is generating a static library but i´m not really sure if it is the same ´cause my A.lib and my A.a have a significant size difference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this blog
https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2006/fall/cs301/lecture/12_04_linker.html

To link objects into libraries we use
**ar cr foo.a foo.o** in Linux
and **link /lib /out:foo.lib foo.obj** on Windows.

But, the problem I had was in fact that I also wanted to link libraries into the out library.
If you need to do this you have to use
ar crsT libab.a liba.a libb.a
I found this on  [Linking static libraries to other static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries)