# How do you build for Basic 64-bit Amazon Linux from Arch Linux?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, compilation, g++, amazon-ami

I figured it wouldn't work, but i just uploaded my program file from local machine to a new instance on Amazon EC2. Than tried to run it:

```
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-14-2A-1A ~]$ ./webserver.net
-bash: ./webserver.net: /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Apparently there is no `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. It is a 64 bit Instance.

How would i compile/link on local machine targeting the EC2 instance.  I don't want to build it on the instance.

My Makefile

```
OBJECTS= ./obj/hello.o
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/lib -lwt -lwthttp

./bin/webserver.net : $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -o ./bin/webserver.net $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

./obj/hello.o : ./src/hello.cpp 
    g++ -c ./src/hello.cpp -o ./obj/hello.o 

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    -rm -f obj/*.o bin/webserver.net core *~ src/*~
```

**Update** Statically linked file. There were undefined references until I added each library manually and in the right order. Is this necessary? or am I doing it wrong?

```
g++ -static -pthread -o ./bin/out.net ./obj/hello.o -lwthttp -lwt  -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_program_options -lboost_random -lboost_signals -lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex -lboost_serialization -lboost_date_time -lssl -lcrypto -lz -ldl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ugly but simple solution might be to link statically your program.

A more elaborate solution could be to mimic the environment of the EC2 instance in e.g. a `chroot`-ed environment on your local machine.

In between you might copy the EC2's /usr/include and /usr/lib/libc.so... etc.. locally, but that is risky.

Perhaps also you could compile locally, and link on the EC2... (but that might not work)

Comment: Will mark as correct as soon as I get it to work. Currently building boost and wt static libraries.

Comment: Works great. Thanks. Had a small side question I added above if you know the answer.

Comment: I thought that you tried the `chroot` approach (perpahs using and configuring the `schroot` package and command).

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic library `lib*.so` can be built with dependencies on other dynamic libraries. (for instance, try `ldd /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so` or `ldd` on some other system `*.so` library on your machine).

A static library `lib*.a` is essentially only a mix of `*.o` object files and don't know its dependencies.

So when linking statically, you need indeed to link all the libraries, in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks. my next question "Can i just join all these files together?" was already answered on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128/how-to-combine-several-c-c-libraries-into-one)