# Can I static link a framework to another framework?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, webkit, static-linking

I have a custom built WebKit.framework and WebCore.framework (a forked version of Apple's Webkit and WebCore).  WebKit has a dependency on WebCore.  WebCore is currently 30 MB which is too big.

I know I am not using all of WebCore, so I was thinking that if I could statically link WebCore into WebKit to strip all the unused code out of WebCore to shrink WebCore.

So can I statically link a framework into another framework?  WebCore is not a static lib currently.

Is this possible? and how?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you can't link frameworks/libs together. you can combine multiple static libs into one .a (see: [How to combine several C/C++ libraries into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128/how-to-combine-several-c-c-libraries-into-one)), but that's not really of any use to you.