# Linking static lib with other static libs

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, libxml2, unix-ar

I'm writing a static lib that needs to handle XML. I want it to include everything that is necessary out of the box but I don't know how to make other static libs link to it, namely libxml2.

I pass the `-c` flag to gcc to generate `.o` that `ar` then uses to create the lib. What magic flag combination must I pass to have my static lib swallow libxml2?

Comment: [Does this related question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13128/2065121) help at all?

Comment: @RogerRowland - it does. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Well, it's already an answer from someone else - just upvote it in the linked question, all I did was search.

Comment: @RogerRowland I've voted to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: Good move - I've done the same.

Comment: So I personally was frustrated that there isn't a better answer than the one that I gave. I've asked for a better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682749/can-i-create-a-static-lib-that-links-against-other-static-libs-without-extractin

Comment: Isn't that what your build system is suppose to do?

Answer (score 4):

libraries don't just swallow other libraries. there's two solutions to do what you want that i can think of.

1. link with both libraries in the final target specifying the new
   library first.
2. copy the libxml2 library and just use the lib tool
   to add your objects to it.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, what's been most effective for me is to extract all the `.o`s from the static library and then include them with your `.o`s to make a single `.a`

So you could look at the contents of `libxml2.a` with `ar t libxml2.a`
Let's say for simplicity that it only contained: `xml2a.o` and `xml2b.o`
You want to combine those with your `mine.o` to make `mine.a`

You'll need to first do `ar x libxml2.a` to get out `xml2a.o` and `xml2b.o`
Then do `ar cr mine.a mine.o xml2a.o xml2b.o`

[A simple explanation](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/ar-command-examples/) of the most widely used `ar` commands, though I've probably summarized what you'd get from it here.

Comment: Reaching the same conclusion here.

Comment: @Cocoaster if you come up with something better let me know. Cause this solution works, but man is it ugly, particularly in my case where I have to link 5 `.a`s

Comment: Doesn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662999/static-lib-ranlib-cant-find-symbols

Comment: Just to confirm, you are including the headers of xml2 into the gcc compilation of your `.o` right?

Comment: I simply run the Makefile that comes with libxml2. I include all .h files that libxml2 in my code, just to be safe.

Comment: Fixed the problem. It was me, not the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Manually merge the objects into a new static library instance:

```
ar -x libx.a
ar -x liby.a
ar -c libz.a  *.o
```