# What is the best approach to simplify linking to my library?

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I want to build a library which is easy to use and link to. Therefore, I do not want the user of my library to bother with building and linking against the libraries my library uses. What is the best approach of managing and building/linking the dependencies for your own library in order to assure the most simple usage of it?

E.g.: My library uses CURL and OpenSSL. Building and linking on Windows with those dependencies is a pain. I want to avoid this pain to the users of my library.

I use CMake for building.

Related to: [Combine libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128/how-to-combine-several-c-c-libraries-into-one) and [Linking static libraries to other static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries)

Comment: Automate linking process by providing INSTALL section in cmake or by taking advantage of some dependency manager like [Conan](https://conan.io/).

Comment: Only specific platforms like Linux? Or different platforms?

Comment: @Werner Henze, in general. Eventhough installing/linking is easy on Linux, building the same library on Windows might be a pain (caused by dependency installation, e.g. OpenSSL)