# Qt .pro combine libraries

Tags: windows, qt, mingw, qmake, .a

I have a subdirs Qt project composed of :

- an external (not made by me) lib
- an internal (made by me) lib using the external lib
- an application using the internal lib

I am on Windows using mingw as compiler

When compiling the libraries I have no issues, everything seems to work fine.

But when I compile the application, I get an ld error : undefined reference to external lib functions (called from internal libs function).

I think this is because when compiling the internal library these method are not called therefore not loaded and this is why it can't find them.

Is there a way to combine the 2 libraries (or at least to force the compiler/linker to resolve the symbols) when compiling the internal library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix my issue.

In the pro file of my internal lib :

- I changed the TARGET value from `internal_lib` to `internal_lib_unlinked`.
- I added a new line `QMAKE_POST_LINK += ar crsT $$DESTDIR/libinternal_lib.a $$DESTDIR/libinternal_lib_unlinked.a path/to/libexternal_lib.a`

This is hacky but it works.

Found thanks to [How to combine several C/C++ libraries into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128/how-to-combine-several-c-c-libraries-into-one)